# Long Loop in masm

Tags: assembly

jmp instruction can jump between -128 bytes ~ 127 bytes
So When I want to jmp out of range, the assembly book said "use long loop"
and a code it is

```
LongLoop macro dest
  local A1, A2
  loop A1
  jmp A2
A1:
   jmp dest
A2:
endm
```

and use LongLoop like this

```
mov ecx, 100
L1:
   ....
   ....
   LongLoop L1
```

I think the code change

```
mov ecx, 100
L1:
   ....
   ....
   jmp A2
   A1:
      jmp L1
   A2:
```

I wonder "jmp L1" is possible.

In case of using loop instead of LongLoop, "loop L1" make jump to L1.
The reason to use LongLoop is "loop L1" can't jump to L1 as it is out of range.
I think When I use LongLoop, "jmp L1" is still out of range.

why is it possible??

Comment: *"So When I want to jmp out of range, the assembly book said "use long loop""* I can't figure out a reason why the book would be teaching you this. Surely they should have said "use a long *jump*". Any book teaching the `LOOP` instruction is highly suspect, unless it is speaking specifically about the 8088/8086.

Comment: "I think the code change..." Beware that you forget an important line here: The `loop A1` instruction (that you forgot) just above the `jmp A2` instruction is most important. Without it you don't have a loop at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `loop` opcode is limited to a one-byte signed displacement from the program counter (PC).  Conditional Jumps also have this limit (at least in 16-bit code).  An unconditional Jump is not limited to a one-byte displacement, thus the `jmp` opcodes in your macro can reach as far as they need to.

Comment: On a 386 or later processor you can encode conditional branches [Jcc](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_146.html) with a rel16 encoding (in 16-bit code) so the jump target can be -32768 to +32767. There isn't a rel16 for of LOOP though.